# jQuery for(x in y) loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, the variable "`key`" isn't capitalized even though any other variables, such as steve[j], are capitalized if they replace "`key`" in the call to the  function `capitaliseFirstLetter()`.

Why?

```
for(key in aray) {
    steve = aray[key];
    for(j = 0; j < steve.length; j++) {
        diff = steve[j].slice(key.length);
        if(diff == "") {
            diff = "_";
        }
        diffs.push(diff);
        var firstLetterUpper = /^[A-Z]/.test(steve[j]);
        if(firstLetterUpper) {
            capitaliseFirstLetter(key)
            alert(key])
        }
    }
}

function capitaliseFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: Note: `if(diff == "")` looks like a typo. Shouldn't that be checking for spaces between words?

Comment: Another typo here: `alert(key])` <-- notice the `]`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: diffs is not defined

Comment: steve[j] is a letter or another string? how does your `aray` look? multi level?

Comment: diffs is defined earlier on and is checking to see if an ending is "er", or "en" or no ending, diff = "" is no ending and should be replaced by "_". This all works and is not the problem I am facing. alert(key) was a typo, sorry. The array is indeed multi level but works with any other variable than "key"

Answer (score 6):

In

```
key = capitaliseFirstLetter(key)
alert(key)
```

a string object is passed to the function by value. So it's not changing, and you should reassign the value.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code with your change... this is not the *only* problem.

Comment: I'm answering key question. I wasn't asked to fix developer's errors

Comment: What do you mean by reassign the value? I tried "key1 = key" and then passing key1 to the function but that didn't work. Sorry about the typo's

Comment: you must catch the response of capitaliseFirstLetter()... capitaliseFirstLetter(key); alert(key]) show the original value of key

Comment: i think this is overwhelming for him... first of all he must know that 'function return' means...

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to captitalise each word it can be done more simply as:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UgT3x/

```
for (key in aray) {
    var steve = aray[key];
    console.log(toTitleCase(steve));
    // if you want to change the aray value
    aray[key] = toTitleCase(steve);
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: i think this is overwhelming for him... first of all he must know that 'function return' means...

Comment: @florin.prisecariu: I disagree. `toTitleCase` is a black box function. It is then a "who cares how it works" scenario :)

Comment: I only want to capitalise words that were capitalized in the originally, hence the check var firstLetterUpper = /^[A-Z]/.test(steve[j]);

Comment: @user2343618: Sorry, if the test is met, then why capitalize it again? I must admit I am having a hard time figuring out what this code is *meant to do* :) **Can you please explain the overall aim in your question?**

Comment: @ TrueBlueAussie , sorry, i was not referring to your solution, but to all this ticket... he has a lot of errors in his code and also he should learn some basic JS before doing all that stuff...